# Reading/Writing tags or keywords using Apple Photos SDK

Tags: swift, sdk, tags, keyword, apple-photos

Does anybody know if Apple’s Photos SDK allows us to fetch, or even modify tags on assets stored in the user’s Photos library?

From the official docs I understand that the SDK allows us to change the « favorite » status, show/hide assets, or even find an asset’s location, but I couldn’t find a way to extract a photo’s tags (keywords) stored by the macOS Photos app.

Is it a feature lacking from the current Photos SDK, or is there any way I can access these metadata?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample how you can get Metadata using [CIImage.properties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/ciimage/1437733-properties) from `PHAsset`.

```
fileprivate extension PHAsset {
    func printMetadata() {
        let options = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()

        requestContentEditingInput(with: options) { (contentEditingInput: PHContentEditingInput?, _) -> Void in
            let img = CIImage(contentsOf: contentEditingInput!.fullSizeImageURL!)
            print(img?.properties)
        }
    }
}
```

For iCloud stored images add the following line:

```
options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
```

I haven't found Image metadata in `PHAsset` as well.

For writing `CIImage` metadata you can try `CIImage.settingProperties(_:)` method.

Comment: Thanks, I've added an upvote, however I didn't specify it in the question since I thought the SDK existed the same for both platforms, but it looks like a few methods are missing from the macOS SDK. For example, oddly enough, `requestContentEditingInput(with:completionHandler:)` does not seem to exist on macOS (confirmed here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phasset/1624061-requestcontenteditinginput). I will have to try with a sample iOS app to check your code then.

Comment: @Romain, i haven't personally worked with Images on macOS, but some superficial research shows that [CGImageProperties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimageproperties) might work. According to documentation it should also work on other platforms. BTW,  [CGImageProperties](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimageproperties) contains a lot of useful information on EXIF data that you might be interested in. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again @fewlinesofcode. But after doing some tests on iOS with my own Photos library, I can fetch photos and inspect their IPTC and EXIF metadata using the code you provided, however my keywords are nowhere to be found in this data :(
I suspect keywords are not synced to the iOS Photos library (since Photos for iOS does not support keywords or smart albums), and on macOS, they may not even be stored as IPTC or EXIF metadata but in a way that's not accessible to developers at the moment instead (not that I can think of, at least...).